# magento 2 show attribute value in one block per selected dropdown configurable products

Tags: javascript, php, magento2

We have configurable products with dropdown options. Dropdown options of a configurable product contain the labels of child product. For example:

```
30"W X 30"H
30"W X 42"H
48"W X 30"H
60"W X 30"H
```

What I am trying to achieve: Anytime one item is selected, one block under the selected item show up and show the lead time in this block.

What I am doing:

1. Added one block called "leadTime" to app/design/frontend/Fallback/default/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

   getAttributeId() ?>]"
               data-selector="super_attribute[getAttributeId() ?>]"
              data-validate="{required:true}"
              id="attributegetAttributeId() ?>"
              class="super-attribute-select">
              
              
              getAttributeId() ?>" style="display: none;">Show Lead Time!!!
2. Edit code of app/design/frontend/Fallback/default/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js to show value of attribute of leadtime in the block above.

Could anybody give me a hint how to solve this task?

Thanks a lot for your help!